# Stateful implementation of F-algebra

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats, cats-effect

Consider the following simple F-algebra

```
trait Test[F[_]] {
  def add(i: Int): F[Unit]
}
```

I want to provide implementation of it that tracks all of the added values and adds those that have not been added yet. It has to be done in a thread safe manner.

The "best" implementation I could come up with is using `MVar[F, Ref[F, List[Int]]]`. Here is how it looks like

```
def statefulMutexTest[F[_]: Concurrent] = {
  val mvarRef: F[MVar[F, Ref[F, List[Int]]]] =
    for {
      ref  <- Ref.of[F, List[Int]](List.empty[Int])
      mvar <- MVar.of[F, Ref[F, List[Int]]](ref)
    } yield mvar

  mvarRef map { mvar =>
    new Test[F] {
      override def add(i: Int): F[Unit] =
        mvar.take.bracket(ref =>
          for {
            list    <- ref.get
            _       <- if (!list.contains(i)) ref.set(list :+ i) else Applicative[F].unit
          } yield ())(mvar.put)
    }
  }
}
```

It looks pretty messy, but works as expected. I initially thought of using `StateT`, but I don't like the idea that statefulness is exported to clients.

Comment: AFAIK this is not what is called "F-algebra". This is "algebra F". "F-algebra" would be `F[A] => A` and is about combining/extraction, and you have `Int => F[Unit]`.

Comment: Also why use both `Ref` and `MVar`? `Ref` would be enough in your case.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok The reason for `MVar` is that I wanted to provide "mutual exclusion" access to the state (`List[Int]`). In case some effectful computation is involved in the `add` logic it does not seem possible to throw `MVar` away.

Comment: `Ref` [already](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/concurrency/ref.html) provides mutual exlusion

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Imagine the case where one needs to log an event into a database in case the value was added to the `List`. We have the following sequence of actions that are obligated to be atomic: `read the current state` -> `add if not exist` -> `log into database` -> `update state`. If writing into a db fails the state should not be updated. In this case `Ref::update` method would not work.

Comment: In such case I would look at neither Ref nor MVar but STM implementation like https://github.com/TimWSpence/cats-stm

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Have never heard about it. Thanks for information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `Ref` is everything I would normally use for such case and `Test` here is just a domain-specific wrapper:

```
object Test {

  def of[F[_]: Sync]: F[Test[F]] =
    Ref.of[F, Set[Int]](Set.empty).map(ref => (i: Int) => ref.update(_ + i).void)
}
```